# diophantine approximation

Tags: diophantine-approximation

For which $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ can one say that $\forall \epsilon > 0$ there $\exists N \geq 1$ such that $\forall i \in \mathbb N$ one has that some $n\in \{1, \dots, N\}$ is a solution to

$$
\min_{m\in \mathbb Z} |\alpha^{in} -  m| \leq \epsilon.
$$

Can one find such a bound $N$ for all real numbers $\alpha$? Can someone see any sufficient conditions on $\alpha$ such that this works out? What about $\alpha = e$, that is  $\alpha^{in} = \exp(in)$?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true for any algebraic integer $\alpha$ having exactly one conjugate outside the unit circle, since for such $\alpha$ the distance from $\alpha^n$ to the nearest integer goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity. I suspect it's a very hard question for other real $\alpha$ --- it's a notoriously hard problem to say anything much about small values of the fractional part of $(3/2)^n$, for example, a question of Mahler related to Waring's problem (Mahler's paper is [here](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=/27013_CD1A0BA09E562FBD362D13ABCCBF96AC_journals__JAZ_JAZ8_02_S1446788700005371a.pdf&cover=Y&code=bb1e617e2a339a93388169c5ae3c5095)).

Comment: (The link does not seem to work.)

Comment: @Andres and all, sorry. The bibliographic reference is K Mahler, An unsolved problem on the powers of $3/2$, J Austral Math Soc 8 (1968) 313-321. Maybe one needs a subscription. Maybe  http://journals.cambridge.org/abstract_S1446788700005371 works better --- it may link to the abstract, from which there seems to be a link to the full article. If that doesn't work, try the Austral Math Soc website.